# How to do a slideout animation between routes

Tags: angular, animation

I managed to get an animation between 2 routes.

Now I want when I go from HomeComponent to DashboardComponent, that the HomeComponent will go up and leaves the screen, meanwhile the DashboardComponent will slide up from the bottom.

I don't have alot of experience with animations, the only thing I have now is a fadein:

```
trigger('routeAnimation', [
    state('*',
      style({
        opacity: 1,
        transform: 'translateX(0)'
      })
    ),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({
        opacity: 0,
        transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
      }),
      animate('0.2s ease-in')
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate('0.5s ease-out', style({
        opacity: 0,
        transform: 'translateY(100%)'
      }))
    ])
  ]);
```

How do I proceed, animate the bottom property of the HomeComponent or are there better ways?

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented and written the appropiate code.

My animations.ts file:

```
import {trigger, state, animate, style, transition} from '@angular/core';

export function routerTransitionTop() {
  return slideToTop();
}

function slideToTop() {
  return trigger('routerTransitionTop', [
    state('void', style({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%'
    })),
    state('*', style({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%'
    })),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(100%)'}),
      animate('1s ease-in-out',
      style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}),
      animate('1s ease-in-out',
      style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}))
    ])
  ]);
}
```